# Why do Gungans lack weapons that are remotely on a par with their other technologies?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

I was re-watching The Phantom Message for the first time last night, with my kids. During the battle sequence between the Gungans and the Federation droids, I was struck by the bizarre mixture of technologies displayed by the Gungans.

To wit: they have fairly advanced protective force-field technology. We also know from earlier sequences that they're capable of building high-tech cities and submarine transports. That's all par for the course for the Star Wars universe.

What eluded me was the reason as to why, given they seem to have access fairly advanced engineering, they're still riding animals into battle, armed with spears and ballistas that lob solid projectiles at the opposition? They don't even seem to use gunpowder. Surely this is just a recipe for slaughter?

EDIT: A couple of commenters are suggesting it's because they have no need for weapons. There are problems with this theory, not least that they live in an environment full of dangerous predatory fish. Even if that were not the case, you would imagine a society capable of building submarines would have tools that would make better improvised weapons than stone-age spears. Also, evidence from books, comics, films etc. would be useful.

Comment: Gunpowder isn't the most efficient type of weaponry when you live underwater. And they're generally just quite a peaceful people who keep to themselves and didn't really have much need for weapons at all, except on a small scale, until the Battle of Naboo. A few spears and things like that was enough for their occasional needs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In which case, they wouldn't need all the shielding tech they've got.

Comment: I always saw that as being the same shielding tech they use to keep their underwater cities dry on the inside (but I don't actually know, of course).

Comment: Maybe it's because they have always been a peaceful race and have never had the need for highly efficient weapons.  Spears work fine against really big fish.

Comment: You call the Gungans "peaceful", but in the film they describe themselves as "warriors" and [have an army](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungan_Grand_Army).

Comment: @William Did they? Sure, an army of Gungans fought in the Battle of Naboo, but wasn’t that pretty much just a makeshift army of all the able-bodied Gungans they could muster? They certainly had some kind of police force beforehand, and I’m guessing they probably had a contingency plan in case they were attacked (by the surface-inhabiting Naboo humans, they’d probably assume), which is where the blue balls and things came in handy. But is there any evidence that they had an actual army before the Battle of Naboo?

Comment: [The road not taken...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Not_Taken_%28short_story%29)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Jar Jar says, "Gungans no dyin' witout a fight. Wesa warriors. Wesa got a grand army."

Comment: @William Ah, well there you go then! I wonder what exactly (apart from outside fishes) this army of theirs has been fighting previously, in their seemingly peaceful, undisturbed, solitary existence…

Comment: Those plasma balls actually seem fairly advanced to me, in that they seem to disable any machinery they come in contact with, even if the method of launching them is not. Perhaps the Gungan weapons are designed to minimize casualties and mainly target machinery, especially if as Richard suggested their main use was intended to be defensive rather than offensive.

Comment: +1 for watching Stars Wars with your kids and teaching them about it !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the film's [Visual Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789447010). In short, the "Grand Army" of the Gungans is actually a holdover from their earlier (historical) conflicts with the surface-dwelling Naboobians as well as acting as a defensive force against the various large creatures that lurk in the Naboo swamps and periodically come up from the planet-core. The army itself comprises representatives from the entire Gungan nation, each contributing some of their forces to the struggle.

> *Long united by treaties, the Gungans do not fight the Naboo or each
>   other. Many years ago they drove off the last invaders to threaten
>   them. Nonetheless they maintain an armed force for tradition and
>   defence against attack by sea monsters. The Grand Army employs both
>   technological wizardry and traditional weaponry. Its primary focus is
>   on defence, for which animal-mounted shield generators are used. For
>   attack, the Gungans hurl plasmic energy balls. Soldiers of the Grand
>   Army are inexperienced, but their resolve comes from a firm sense of
>   duty and justice.* - <sub><sup>Star Wars: Episode 1 - Visual Dictionary</sup></sub>

and

[image]

As to why the Gungan military is so backwards, this is also covered. Simply put, the Gungans openly prefer to have a society that is less "*technological*", enjoying a more pastoral life in their native swamps.

> *A fair but stubborn ruler. Boss Nass resents the arrogance of the
>   Naboo. who regard Gungans as primitive **simply because they do not
>   embrace a technological lifestyle.** He finds it best all round to
>   minimize contact with humans.*

Comment: +1, although you don't really address the bit about why the armylitia’s arsenal is technologically so much less technologically advanced than the rest of their society.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Their army is as advanced as it needs to be. They didn't anticipate fighting a droid force, it seems.

Comment: For a society that didn't anticipate a fight with droids they certainly had a pretty large stockpile of ammunition (those blue balls) that seems specifically designed to incapacitate droids.

Comment: @IanAuld - A large stockpile of ammunition *capable of defeating the sorts of transports you see the Naboobians use*, you mean?"

Comment: @Ian They’re not specifically designed for that. They’re just balls of highly concentrated energy that take out more or less anything they hit by energy overload. We don’t know how long it takes to make them (at least not that I’m aware of), but the [company that makes them](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Otoh_Gunga_Defense_League) may just have gotten really busy getting extra shipments ready once they were told there was going to be an actual battle.